# Read Json From external URL using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm try get the json value from a external url but nothing happens this is the url that i'm using http://uaibh.com/feed/json
 and this is my scrip

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'>
<script>
 function AJAX_JSON_Req( url )
{
var AJAX_req = new XMLHttpRequest();
AJAX_req.open( "GET", url, true );
AJAX_req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

AJAX_req.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if( AJAX_req.readyState == 4 && AJAX_req.status == 200 )
    {
        var response = JSON.parse( AJAX_req.responseText );
        document.write( response.name );
    }
}
AJAX_req.send();
}

AJAX_JSON_Req( 'http://uaibh.com/feed/json' );
```

What is wrong my script or would be my server "host" ?

Comment: The output of your server's script is not valid JSON due to the PHP error at the end of the file.

Comment: You should look at [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) since you already have jquery on the page.